# How can I generate an HTML directory listing of video thumbs and links from a directory?

Tags: html, apache, thumbnails, mp4, preview

This is basically a copy of this guys question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194157/how-can-i-generate-a-thumbnails-from-a-directory-of-images-using-php)

Lets say i have a video directory full of hundreds of tiny mp4 clips, most under a minute. Currently right now i'm using [directorylister](http://www.directorylister.com/) to view my directories on my apache server. It does the trick for the most part, but only because i can't find the answer anywhere on the web.

What i'd like is to be able to run my video folder through a batch process to generate the thumbs into another folder..(identical filenames, only jpg ext instead of mp4 obviously)

So i got my /htdocs/vids here (vid1.mp4,vid2.mp4,etc) and my /htdocs/thumbs there (vid1.jpg,vid2.jpg,etc).. and then a script very similar to directorylister combines the two so i have an HTML index directory list of video links with the thumbnail displaying beside the link:

vid1.jpg - vid1.mp4
vid2.jpg - vid2.mp4
vid3.jpg - vid3.mp4
etc..

Simply put, i am trying to find a way to display the contents of my video folder with a thumb image beside the file, possibly combine the 2 in a table that mirrors a normal directory structure so i can quickly identify the file without clicking on the link to load the video. i don't want to 'reupload' files through an interface, all the files are already there in the directory. I don't want to hand code this in html myself because we're talking hundreds of little files, with more added all the time, so automatic generation of the index is a must. I don't need transcoding or media players embedded, i just let apache serve out the mp4 and have vlc do all the heavy lifting client side.

i just need the directory listing to be punched out with a thumbnail image next to the filename. How this gets done is beyond me. Any help?

Apologies in advance for the complete n00bian that i am. This was a hobby project gone wild.

Comment: so you want an automated way to extract an image from the video to use as a thumbnail... kinda like youtube?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043007/generate-preview-image-from-video-file

Comment: Not really like Yoiutube. Think more like windows explorer. There are 2 view modes in windows explorer that i would like to replicate. Either the 'Large Icons' view (just screenshot+filename), or the 'Content' view (screenshot+filename+datemodified+size, etc)

Comment: if it can be automated to select a frame 10 seconds into the clip, that would be great. Tho extracting the image isn't my primary issue, it's having the picture displayed next to a clickable link of that mp4's file location.

Comment: So its not the image you need but the code to show a image next to a link? use the image AS the link to the MP4? and you want all this to be done for all the files in a directory? what technologies do you want to use? jquery, javascript, angularjs, C#, php, vbscript etc.

Comment: I found something that came extremely close to what im looking for. Its called h5ai ( https://larsjung.de/h5ai/ ). I have it running and it's so close to being perfect EXCEPT that since im running php5.5.15, every version of php_ffmpeg.dll i have tried to install as an extension has failed. FFmpeg is a dead project. I tried Avconv as well, but no joy. I contacted the developer and he doesn't know how to configure it for windows, only linux. So i'm s.o.l until someone figures it out or creates another directory index script.

Comment: well you can also use VLC player instead of FFMPEG

Comment: i should have created a linux partition on my laptop and done this project using ubunto. seems nobody does these on windows machines... here's another creation by someone but only for Linux https://www.npmjs.com/package/thumbsup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abandoned project, instead used a raspberry pi2 with debian Jessie/pixel upgrade, installed ffmpeg, Apache, and used html directory display program H5ai. Mounted windows share into /www/html path, set up ddns and the rest is history.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a console app or batch file that your PHP or something could run then follow post here http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10327812-How-to-install-ffmpeg-php-to-create-thumbnails-from-videos and that will show you a way to use FFMPEG to strip out an image for each video. Hope this gets you closer to what you need.